# what is the difference between conv2d and Conv2D in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am confused with `Conv2D` and `conv2d` in Keras. what is the difference between them? I think the first one is a layer and the second one is a backend function, but what does it mean? in Conv2D we send the number of filters, the size of filters and stride ( `Conv2D(64,(3,3),stride=(8,8))(input))` but in conv2d we use `conv2d(input, kernel, stride=(8,8))` what is kernel is it (64,3,3) and we put number of filter and size together? where should I enter the number of kernels? could you please help me with this issue? Thank you.

**code in pytorch**

```
def apply_conv(self, image, filter_type: str):

        if filter_type == 'dct':
            filters = self.dct_conv_weights
        elif filter_type == 'idct':
            filters = self.idct_conv_weights
        else:
            raise('Unknown filter_type value.')

        image_conv_channels = []
        for channel in range(image.shape[1]):
            image_yuv_ch = image[:, channel, :, :].unsqueeze_(1)
            image_conv = F.conv2d(image_yuv_ch, filters, stride=8)
            image_conv = image_conv.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
            image_conv = image_conv.view(image_conv.shape[0], image_conv.shape[1], image_conv.shape[2], 8, 8)
            image_conv = image_conv.permute(0, 1, 3, 2, 4)
            image_conv = image_conv.contiguous().view(image_conv.shape[0],
                                                  image_conv.shape[1]*image_conv.shape[2],
                                                  image_conv.shape[3]*image_conv.shape[4])

            image_conv.unsqueeze_(1)

            # image_conv = F.conv2d()
            image_conv_channels.append(image_conv)

        image_conv_stacked = torch.cat(image_conv_channels, dim=1)

        return image_conv_stacked
```

**the changed code in Keras**

```
def apply_conv(self, image, filter_type: str):

        if filter_type == 'dct':
            filters = self.dct_conv_weights
        elif filter_type == 'idct':
            filters = self.idct_conv_weights
        else:
            raise('Unknown filter_type value.')
        print(image.shape)

        image_conv_channels = []
        for channel in range(image.shape[1]):
            print(image.shape)
            print(channel)
            image_yuv_ch = K.expand_dims(image[:, channel, :, :],1)
            print( image_yuv_ch.shape)
            print(filters.shape)
            image_conv = Kr.backend.conv2d(image_yuv_ch,filters,strides=(8,8),data_format='channels_first')
           image_conv = Kr.backend.permute_dimensions(image_conv,(0, 2, 3, 1))
            image_conv = Kr.backend.reshape(image_conv,(image_conv.shape[0], image_conv.shape[1], image_conv.shape[2], 8, 8))
            image_conv =  Kr.backend.permute_dimensions(image_conv,(0, 1, 3, 2, 4))
            image_conv = Kr.backend.reshape(image_conv,(image_conv.shape[0],
                                                  image_conv.shape[1]*image_conv.shape[2],
                                                  image_conv.shape[3]*image_conv.shape[4]))

            Kr.backend.expand_dims(image_conv,1)

            # image_conv = F.conv2d()
            image_conv_channels.append(image_conv)

        image_conv_stacked = Kr.backend.concatenate(image_conv_channels, axis=1)

        return image_conv_stacked
```

but when I execute the code, it produces the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 383, in 
>       decoded_noise=JpegCompression()(act11)#16
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py",
>   line 457, in **call**
>       output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
>
> File "", line 169, in call
>       image_dct = self.apply_conv(noised_image, 'dct')
>
> File "", line 132, in apply_conv
>       image_conv = Kr.backend.conv2d(image_yuv_ch,filters,strides=(8,8),data_format='channels_first')
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 3650, in conv2d
>       data_format=tf_data_format)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py",
>   line 779, in convolution
>       data_format=data_format)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py",
>   line 839, in **init**
>       filter_shape[num_spatial_dims]))
>
> ValueError: number of input channels does not match corresponding
>   dimension of filter, 1 != 8

**the new code**

```
for channel in range(image.shape[1]):
            image_yuv_ch = K.expand_dims(image[:, channel, :, :],axis=1)
            image_yuv_ch = K.permute_dimensions(image_yuv_ch, (0, 2, 3, 1))
            image_conv = tf.keras.backend.conv2d(image_yuv_ch,kernel=filters,strides=(8,8),padding='same')
            image_conv = tf.keras.backend.reshape(image_conv,(image_conv.shape[0],image_conv.shape[1], image_conv.shape[2],8,8))
```

**the error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 263, in 
>       decoded_noise=JpegCompression()(act11)#16
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py",
>   line 457, in **call**
>       output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
>
> File "", line 166, in call
>       image_dct = self.apply_conv(noised_image, 'dct')
>
> File "", line 128, in apply_conv
>       image_conv = tf.keras.backend.reshape(image_conv,(image_conv.shape[0],image_conv.shape[1],
>   image_conv.shape[2],8,8))
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py",
>   line 2281, in reshape
>       return array_ops.reshape(x, shape)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py",
>   line 6482, in reshape
>       "Reshape", tensor=tensor, shape=shape, name=name)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 513, in _apply_op_helper
>       raise err
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 510, in _apply_op_helper
>       preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 1146, in internal_convert_to_tensor
>       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
>   line 229, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
>       return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
>   line 208, in constant
>       value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py",
>   line 531, in make_tensor_proto
>       "supported type." % (type(values), values))
>
> TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor.
>   Contents: (Dimension(None), Dimension(4), Dimension(4), 8, 8).
>   Consider casting elements to a supported type.

Comment: See ["Merge" versus "merge", what is the difference?](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3921). Names starting with lower case represent functions that can receive one or more tensors and parameters and produce another tensor. Names starting with upper case represent layers, those do not receive directly and input tensor, instead they produce a callable that can receive the tensor and produce a new one.

Comment: Thank you. now I have a tensor with shape (:,1,32,32) and filters with shape(64,1,8,8), if I use conv2d(image, filters), is it possible or we should have a similarity between filter and image shape? I need that Keras consider 64 filters 8x8 and I am not sure when I used conv2d(image, filters) it does the same thing I need? could you please help me

Comment: If you already have an image tensor and a filters tensor, then use [`tf.nn.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d). With Keras functions you just give the filters size, and Keras creates them for you internally. In any case, it seems your data is not in the default format (I suppose the image is `(batch, channels, height, width)` and the filters `(out_channes, in_channels, height, width)`?). See the `data_format` parameter in the functions and, if you need it, use [`tf.transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose).

Comment: yes, the image shape is (batch, 3,32,32) and now I need to convolve the image with the special filter I make before they are 64 filter 8x8 and I have to convolve them with the image. what should I do for this? is it possible to send filters to conv2d?

Comment: sorry, I use Keras so instead of tf.nn.conv2d I should use keras.backend.conv2d? I had a code in pytorch and I need to change it to Keras. in the pytorch code at first the filter size was (64,8,8) and then squeeze(1) it so I think the size become (64,1,8,8,). due to this I said the filter size is (64,1,8,8). I add the code above that I changed it to Keras

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tensorflow and Keras now are using `channel_last` convention. So first you should 
permute the channel dim to the last using `K.permute_dimension`. You might try this code in colab.research.google.com to figure out yourself.

### First question:

- `conv2d` is a function to perform 2D convolution [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/conv2d)
- `keras.layers.Conv2D()` will return an instance of class `Conv2D` which perform convolution function. See more [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D)

```py
# The second 
import keras
conv_layer = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=8, strides=(4, 4), padding='same')
```

Basically, they differ from the way to define and the way to use. `K.conv2d` is used inside `keras.layers.Conv2D` when `conv_layer` apply convolution on some input `x` such as `conv_layer`.

> The example below may help you to understand it easier the difference between `say_hello` and `SayHello`.

```py
def say_hello(word, name):
    print(word, name)


class SayHello():

    def __init__(self, word='Hello'):
        self.word = word
        pass

    def __call__(self, name):
        say_hello(self.word, name)


say_hello('Hello', 'Nadia') #Hello Nadia

sayhello = SayHello(word='Hello') # you will get an instance `sayhello` from class SayHello

sayhello('Nadia') # Hello Nadia
```

### Second question:

- `kernel` here is a tensor of shape (kernel_size, kernel_size, in_channels, out_channels)
- If you want to get the `image_conv` of shape (8, 8, 64) then the `strides=(4,4)`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

image = tf.random_normal((10,3, 32, 32))
print(image.shape) # shape=(10, 3, 32, 32)

channel = 1
image_yuv_ch = K.expand_dims(image[:, channel,:,:], axis=1) # shape=(10, 1, 32, 32)
image_yuv_ch = K.permute_dimensions(image_yuv_ch, (0, 2, 3, 1)) # shape=(10, 32, 32, 1)

# The first K.conv2d
in_channels = 1
out_channels = 64 # same as filters
kernel = tf.random_normal((8, 8, in_channels, out_channels)) # shape=(8, 8, 1, 64)

image_conv = tf.keras.backend.conv2d(image_yuv_ch, kernel=kernel, strides=(4, 4), padding='same')
print(image_conv.shape) #shape=(10, 8, 8, 64)


# The second 
import keras
conv_layer = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=8, strides=(4, 4), padding='same')
image_conv = conv_layer(image_yuv_ch)
print(image_conv.shape) #shape=(10, 8, 8, 64)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, David. I changed the code base on your suggestion, but when I want to reshape the image_conve it produces an error that I put above. do you know why does it happen?

Comment: its another question. You got error because the new shape is not consistent with old shape. I cant reshape (10, 2) into (100,5) but its ok to reshape it into (2,5,2) :) you should print the old and figure out the suitable new shape.

Comment: when I test the code with some test data like image=K.random.randint(4,shape=(2,32,32,1)) and filters= K.random.randint(4,shape(8,8,1,64)) it works well and does not produce this error but when I try to test my network and sent the output tensor of the network layer to this function, it produces this error:(((((

Comment: your code is too complicated as I see :) you should simplify it to first help yourself understand what under the hood :)

Comment: yes, I did it. the output shape of conv2d is (?,4,4,64) and in next line of code I try to change it to (?,4,4,8,8) but I do not know why it produces this error?! because the multiplication of shapes is equal in both of them!!

Comment: but my code is the same as your code, I simplify it and the error is for reshape, but I do not know why?!

Comment: I don't add the code of reshape :) I just only answer you posted questions.

Comment: yes, I know :) and I also know the error is for reshape line but I do not know why?! because the multiplication of shapes are the same in both of them:( ( ?,4,4,64) = (?,4,4,8,8)

Comment: I modified my code and error. could you please help me with your suggestions?

Comment: OK, I find it:) when I used( image_conv.shape[0],image_conv.shape[1], image_conv.shape[2],8,8) it produced this error because the first three type are Dimension and 8 , 8 are simple number when I change the shape to (-1,4,4,8,8) the error is solved.

Comment: is it true? I say the true thing?

Comment: I think you are correct. then did you solve your problem yet? Ive been out for meeting.

Comment: Thank you. with these changes, the code worked and did not produce the error, but  I am not sure it is true or not, because when I use for example int(image.shape[0]) it produces the same error! how can I cast from Dimension type to int?

Comment: sorry, could you please tell me what clone() do in this line of code?        self.jpeg_mask[:, :image_shape[1], :image_shape[2]].clone()